# Adding interval to current timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date

I want to add an interval of 23 hours to the current date and time in PostgreSQL. The query should look something like the following:

`SELECT timestamp LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) + interval '23 hours';`

For some reason, the preceding statement returns an error. What could be wrong here and why is it not working?

Comment: A `date` is very different in nature from a `timestamp`, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove TimeStamp keyword

```
SELECT LOCALTIMESTAMP(0) + interval '23 hours'
```

or use

```
SELECT now() + interval '23 hours'
```